# Fetching the duration of Current running SQL Server JOB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs

Fetching the duration of currently runnig Job in SQL Server.

```
exec msdb..sp_help_job @execution_status = 1
exec xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, garbage
```

These stored procedure only return "last_run_time" which is the last time the job ran.

Comment: And from when it last ran, you cannot work out the duration? `datediff(minute,<when it ran>,getdate())`

Comment: Actually it gives us "when it ran"=when it last time successfully run not the one which is running currently !

Comment: Okay I haven't used `xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs`. I normally go straight to `msdb..sysjobhistory`

Comment: yes `msdb..sysjobhistory` also only provides previous jobs last run time.As its name shows job history.

Comment: Are you sure you've tried it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260416(v=sql.80).aspx There is a status of "In progress" there

Comment: Yes `run_status` gives only the status about the job not the time duration it has been in execution but yeah you can calculate from it too by continuously comparing it to current time from `getdate()` or from front end but continuously getting its status.

Comment: I posted an answer by that i achieved the desired result thanks a lot for you feedback  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msdb.dbo.sysjobs
master.dbo.sysprocesses

I achieved this result by joining the above mention tables and getting login time from the processes.